# SQL Allow One Return Value for Field

Tags: sql

In my office, it is common people who belong to two departments. For a query, I want to limit it so each person is only associated with one department.

For example, here are two HR tables:

table1

```
ID   |  Last_Name | Department
--------------------------------
 1        Doe        Informatics
 2        Miller     Database Management
 2        Miller     Informatics
 3        Johnson    Engineering
 4        Mitchell   Database Management
 4        Mitchell   Engineering
```

table2

```
ID   |  Date_of_sale
--------------------------------
 1        8-2-2012        
 1        1-4-2003     
 2        5-23-2000     
 2        1-17-2003
 2        12-30-2001
 2        9-8-2013
 3        4-19-2013
 4        3-8-2015
 4        11-8-2013
 4        2-12-2007
```

I want to do something like:

```
SELECT Last_Name, FIRST(Department), Date_of_Sale 
From column1, 
FROM column1 JOIN column2 ON column1.id=column2.id
GROUP BY Last_Name
```

Which would return:

```
          Last_Name | Department |     Date_of_sale 
       ----------------------------------------
        Doe         Informatics            8-2-2012
        Doe         Informatics            1-4-2003
        Miller      Database Management    5-23-2000
        Miller      Database Management    1-17-2003
        Miller      Database Management    12-30-2001
        Miller      Database Management    9-8-2013    
        Johnson     Engineering            4-19-2013
        Mitchell    Database Management    3-8-2015
        Mitchell    Database Management    11-8-2013
        Mitchell    Database Management    2-12-2007
```

Where each individual now only has one department associated with them.

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: Not sure which duplicate is applicable without knowing your RDBMS.   Please find your duplicate and flag it.   : )   https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=stack+overflow+return+only+one+value+from+lookup+table&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=stack+overflow+return+only+one+value+from+lookup+table&gs_l=hp....0.0.5.303453...........0.MXi4g7W_Gok#safe=active&q=stack+overflow+sql+join+only+one+row

Comment: So did you figure out? What is the question? What is your desired output? What does column 2 have to do with the question?

Comment: Using a data warehouse that uses both MYSQL and SQL Server RDBMS.  In the end, SQL Server is what worked.

Comment: Sorry had to step away earlier due to an emergency phone call...

Ultimatey, I do not believe the data type of the Date_of_sale column was relevant.  I am passing this data to Tableau where I am doing a calculation basically to sum how many times "Date_of_sale" appeared per person.

Comment: The desired output is the last return.  The reason for including the column2 join is to simulate how the result will look in the end (basically multiple records with one department type per individual.)  If I did not have column2 (changing to table2) the fix would be one record per person.

Thank you for the effort to include the MySQL solution as well.  I have actually been storing the data in both RDBMS types (was originally testing on MySQL but had to move production to SQL Sever) and am learning from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With out knowing your RDBMS giving specific answer is not as easy.  A general answer that woks on most systems would be to use a nested select with aggregation:

```
SELECT c1.ID, c1.Last_name, c1.Department, c2.Date_of_Sale
FROM
    (SELECT
       ID
       ,Last_name
       ,MIN(Department) as Department
    FROM
       column1
    GROUP BY
       ID
       ,Last_name) c1
    INNER JOIN column2 c2
    ON c1.ID = c2.ID
```

Then on SQL-SERVER and most other RDBMS that support common table expressions and window functions you can create a partitioned ROW_NUMBER() to choose what you want (note the cte can also be a nested select instead.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  ID ORDER BY Department) as RowNumber
    FROM
       column1
)

SELECT
    c1.Id
    ,c1.Last_name
    ,c1.Department
    ,c2.Date_of_Sale
FROM
    cte c1
    INNER JOIN column2 c2
    ON c1.Id = c2.Id
WHERE
    c1.RowNumber = 1
```

That is a typical way of doing it if you will somehow put a presedence on which department you will return, e.g. Record Creation Date...But if window functions are supported and you don't really care which department you can grab the partitioned MIN() or MAX() which would just be the ascending order of the records in 1 select statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c1.ID
    ,c1.Last_name
    ,MIN(c1.Department) OVER (PARTITION BY c1.ID) as Department
    ,c2.Date_of_Sale
FROM
    column1 c1
    INNER JOIN column2 c2
    ON c1.ID = c2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this depending on the type of SQL you are using and how you want to select the department for each last name.

Here are a couple examples using **MySQL**.

1. Select the department that is listed first:

   ```
   SELECT id, last_name, 
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(department), ',', 1) AS Department
   FROM column1
   GROUP BY id, last_name
   ```
2. Select the department by alphabetical order:

   ```
   SELECT id, last_name, MIN(department)
   FROM column1
   GROUP BY id, last_name
   ```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67bf3/8

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to get the first department for each user, then join to the second table:

```
SELECT  t1.Last_Name, 
        t1.Department, 
        t2.Date_of_Sale 
    FROM (select id, Last_Name, MIN(Department) Department from column1 group by id, Last_Name) t1
    JOIN column2 t2 ON 
        t1.id = t2 .id
```